# Images distorted / corrupted when viewed via Google Cached image server

Tags: image, gmail

Currently confirmed when viewing the email on OSX Firefox Gmail and Android Gmail app.

Our main marketing email logo is getting distorted when viewed via Google's cached image server.

Gmail has the correct reference [to the site](https://econsultancy.com/assets/redesign/mailers/daily_pulse_logo-d862dbafce633e71238a4a7bcb205751.gif)

[image: this]

But, when cached and linked via `ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy`, it gets messed up!

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Google compress the image before adding it to the cached image server. This affect different file formats differently. PNG image without alpha channel seems to be best option to avoid distortion.

Thanks to @ian-vaughan for helping out!